# how to create a form containing a photo frame with ITEXT

Tags: itext, frame

I'm trying to create a fillable PDF file with iText 7. So far, I've managed to generate all my pages and all my fields. However, I have a problem creating a frame to upload a photo

Comment: Please paste your sample code, or error message

Comment: The PDF standard does not define AcroForm form fields for photos (or images in general). Some PDF generators *emulate* image fields using a push button with some JavaScript events allowing to set a new image as the appearance of that button. You can create something similar using iText 7. Furthermore, there are some PDF generators which actually create a XFA form (which is a XML format unrelated to PDF but which can use a PDF file as transport container). iText does not explicitly support creating these but you can create the XML using an arbitrary XML library and add it to a PDF using iText.